# findByIdAndRemove via Href is giving me 404

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

My Link to delete an Object is giving me 404, when I click on the link, it goes to localhost:3000/account/5cf3ea30a19df73f449e72f2/delete, but just gives me a 404, however in post man, when I put that exact same url in, it works perfectly fine.

```
exports.deleteAccount = (req, res) => {

    Accounts.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send('Deleted successfully!');
    });
};
```

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const accountController = require('../controllers/accounts-controller')

router.post('/add', accountController.addAccount);
router.delete('/:id/delete', accountController.deleteAccount);

module.exports = router;
```

```
a(href="/account/5cf3ea30a19df73f449e72f2/delete") Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine.

When type a url inside a web browser it always sends a GET request to "get" the page. When you type http://localhost:3000/account/5cf3ea30a19df73f449e72f2/delete into your browser you are trying to "get" that resource. Since you only  specified the `/:id/delete` route to match requests that contain a `DELETE` header you are getting a 404.

To find out more about HTTP request methods and their meaning, have a look at the documentation on the [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Comment: So if I change the route.delete to route.get it should work?

Comment: You're welcome! Would you mind marking the answer as the correct answer? :)